Google Workspace sandbox environment
I'd like to test a Google Apps Script that I'm building and I'm looking for a place to test it. It's a script that will be executed by a service account and collecting information on users in an OU. The script is built to collect inbound/outbound emails/calendar invitations and sync them to Salesforce as tasks/events.
Is there a way to create a partition in my production org to test out my script? Or do I have to create a new workspace for this project? I'd like to deploy this as a web-app that can be deployed to users in my workspace. I'm not the Workspace admin, but will be working with that team closely.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question needs more focus, details and clarity. First, please clarify what you mean by "test a Google Apps Script" and elaborate on how you plan to conduct the test. Is this an Editor add-on, a Workspace Add-on, a web app, ... ? Are you a Google Workspace Administrator?

Appreciate the feedback here. Let me provide what details I can - I'm not a developer by trade so I'll try my best to explain. I'm trying to make a workspace add on that can collect information on users in an OU.  The script syncs inbound and outbound messages to Salesforce. I'm not the workspace admin, but will be working with our admin to deploy this.

Thanks for your reply. Please [edit] the question to make it more focused and add all the relevant details directly on it.

What I have done is creating a test OU, but as you might've noticed is that some settings are global to the whole ORG and can't be configured to tarjet OU.
If the script is only gathering info from user and you don't need to enable/disable any configuration that affects the whole ORG (like allowing domain-wide delegation to impersonate users using a Service Account), then a separate test OU could suffice. otherwise, consider getting a cheap domain and a free trial

I'm thinking that a service account is the route that I have to take. The intention was to run the script as different users to collect activities. I'll look into a free trial. Thank you!
